How to use iframe in flutter
I wanted to use the following iframe in flutter
<iframe
src="https://www.example"
width="100%"
style="height: 100%; min-height: 700px"
frameborder="0"
\\\>\</iframe\>

i tried using webview and html package but it won't work
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatbotWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatbotWidgetState createState() => _ChatbotWidgetState();
}

class _ChatbotWidgetState extends State<ChatbotWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Register the chatbot iframe
    final iframe = html.IFrameElement()
      ..src = 'https://www.chatbase.co/chatbot-iframe/e722IpwL3HEm27U2KOodE'
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..style.width = '100%'
      ..style.height = '100%'
      ..style.minHeight = '700px';

    // Add script to head for chatbot
    final scriptConfig = html.ScriptElement()
      ..type = 'text/javascript'
      ..innerHtml = '''
        window.embeddedChatbotConfig = {
          chatbotId: "e722IpwL3HEm27U2KOodE",
          domain: "www.chatbase.co"
        };
      ''';

    final script = html.ScriptElement()
      ..src = 'https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js'
      ..defer = true;

    html.document.head!.append(scriptConfig);
    html.document.head!.append(script);

    // Register the iframe element
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => iframe,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'iframeElement'),
    );
  }
}

I know that the webview is deprecated so I tried html but the result still the same, it won't show the iframe.
This is my first time using flutter so I am sorry if my code still a mess.

Are you perhaps not building for Web? HTMLElementView is for Flutter Web only:

This widget only works on Flutter web. To embed web content on other platforms, consider using the webview_flutter plugin.

Please elaborate on what issues you are facing when using webview_flutter and I'd happily assist!
